# React is not rerendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working in react components today and have worked in them before but still consider myself pretty nooby when it comes to it.

Problem: My setState is refreshing and changing this.state but my component isn't re-rendering at all. I can watch my state change and even manually change it but it still wont change any of my conditional renders. I am trying to conditionally render a ProcessingBox and a JobsGrid But I can't get anything to load.

Attempts: I have attempted to console log all around the Components and even in the function I am getting the correct output I want but wont reload the component. I have also tried doing a forceUpdate but that still didn't work. Aslo tried asyncing the componentDidMount but no luck. My next theories are something to do with styled components and also something maybe missing from npm that I may have missed.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { JobsGrid, ProcessingBox, JobsContainer } from './styled';

class Employment extends Component {
  state = {
    categories: [],
    jobs: [],
    activeJob: {},
    activeCategory: {},
    processing: false
  };


  componentDidMount() {
    this.getCategories();
  }

  getCategories = async () => {
    this.setState({ processing: true });
    await fetch('url', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer token',
      }
    }).then(res => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        this.setState({ categories: result.data, processing: false });
      });
  };

  isLoading = (processing) => {
    console.log(processing);
    if (processing) {
      return (
        <ProcessingBox>
          <img src="/build/img/loading.GIF" alt="" />
        </ProcessingBox>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <JobsGrid>
          <div className="container">
            <div>Hi</div>
          </div>
        </JobsGrid>
      )
    }
  };


  render() {

    return (
      <JobsContainer>
        {
          this.isLoading(this.state.processing)
        }
      </JobsContainer>
    );
  }
}

const
  element = document.querySelector('#employment');

if (element) {
  render(
    <Employment />,
    element
  );
}
```

Comment: how many times does this logs console.log(processing) ? and are the value updated?

Comment: @ibtsam it updates three times going like this (False), (True), then (False)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your getCategories function as this,

```
getCategories = async () => {
 this.setState({ processing: true });
 const res = await fetch('url', { headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer token',} });
 const result = await res.json();
 this.setState({ categories: result.data, processing: false });
};
```

I think you are using then and await at the same time, await is used for waiting for a promise, See if it solves your problem,

Hope it helps

Comment: I forgot this but still didn't fix the problem. It looks like the DOM just isn't rendering again.

Answer (score 0):

You need add .catch in fetch

```
getCategories = async () => {
    this.setState({ processing: true });
    await fetch('url', {
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer token',
    }
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
            this.setState({ categories: result.data, processing: false });
        })
        .catch(err){
            this.setState({ categories: null, processing: false });
        };
};
```

Comment: I forgot this but still didn't fix the problem. It looks like the DOM just isn't rendering again.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:** Wrong dependencies kept the DOM from rerendering. Basically I didn't even have react installed. Went to a different project that had react installed already and worked like a charm, cleaned some code up and learned a lot about babel. Learn from my mistakes guys

Answer (score -1):

I think your last part should be changed, it should be **`ReactDOM.render()`** instead of **`render()`**

```
if (element) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Employment />,
    element
  );
}
```

Comment: He's importing the render function directly so doesn't need to prefix it. In fact doing this here would throw an error, as `ReactDOM` is undefined.